Why didn't they make the Cyrus Proclamation into a holiday?
When Cyrus issued his edict allowing the Jewish people to return to Eretz Yisrael this was a momentous occasion marking the end of the exile (for those who chose to return). I am surprised that such an event was not marked by any sort of holiday. Do any authorities explain why there is no holiday commemorating the Cyrus edict and return to Tzion?

Maybe they did?

@DoubleAA documentation of such would make for a useful answer.

It may perhaps also be possible to use this as an example to flip the script; considering that when the Jews were allowed to return and even rebuild the Beis Hamikdash (although they were prevented from doing so soon after) there was no holiday instituted, perhaps there need not be one for the Jewish return to Israel in the common era... I'm all in favor of Israel, but this (the prophetically scheduled return to Tzion) does seem like a much more momentous occasion than the formation of a Jewish state without nearly as much fanfare in the way of prophetic paving.

@EthanLeonard to play devil's advocate the return by Ezra was pitiful both in terms of numbers and the types of people, compared to the modern era. But on the other hand no holiday was established when Yehoshua conquered the land either

In modern times , no holiday or commemoration was established in relation to the Balfour Declaration or the UN Resolution of 29 November 1947.

+1 This can be explained on several levels: unlike Purim, they weren't "saved", the Persians were pretty tolerant of the Jews and other religious minorities, in fact, the majority of the exiled Jews stayed in Babylon. Unlike Hannuka, the Jews were not autonomous, so they could not establish the prophecized monarchy.
